# Vitest warning: The current test runner does not support afterEach/teardown hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, vitest

**Problem:**
I am working on a React project using Vite and TypeScript, and I've encountered some warnings while running tests with Vitest and RTL (React Testing Library). Despite the tests running fine, I previously faced issues with not using `cleanup()` breaking some tests. The warnings are as follows:

```
stderr | unknown 
test The current test runner does not support afterEach/teardown hooks. This means we won't be able to run automatic cleanup and you should be calling cleanup() manually.

The current test runner does not support beforeAll/afterAll hooks. This means you should be setting IS_REACT_ACT_ENVIRONMENT manually.
```

**Environment:**

- Running in a devContainer (Node.js & TypeScript image)
- Node version: 20.x

**Dependencies:**

```json
{
  "name": "armada-website",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "test": "vitest",
    "coverage": "vitest --coverage",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@swc/helpers": "^0.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.2.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-istanbul": "^0.29.8",
    "happy-dom": "^12.10.3",
    "jsdom": "^21.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^4.5.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.1",
    "vitest": "^0.29.7"
  },
}
```

**Vite Configuration (`vite.config.ts`):**

```js
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import type { UserConfig } from 'vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import type { InlineConfig } from 'vitest';

interface VitestConfigExport extends UserConfig {
  test: InlineConfig;
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()],
  test: {
    environment: 'happy-dom',
    coverage: {
      provider: 'istanbul',
      lines: 90,
      functions: 90,
      branches: 90,
      statements: 90,
    },
    dir: 'src/__tests__',
  },
  exclude: ['src/__tests__'],
} as VitestConfigExport);
```

**TypeScript Configuration (`tsconfig.json`):**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**Question:**
How can I resolve these warnings to ensure a stable testing environment? Are there specific configurations or versions I should be using with Vitest and RTL to support these features?

**Note**
I was working on a previous project with basically the same settings and versions, and I had no warnings regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vitest expects afterEach to be globally defined, which is not the case  by default.

So try adding the following to your vite config

```
test: {
  ....
  globals: true
}
```

See https://github.com/testing-library/vue-testing-library/issues/296 for more info

Comment: This actually worked thanks! But can you please explain why/how this fixed the issue

Comment: Sure, I'll add some more info